# NoSuchElementException in iframe in frameset

Tags: java, internet-explorer, iframe, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I Am using IE9
Here is some html i want to test, this window opens after I 'click' ADD button

```
>DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd"
><html lang="pl" dir="ltr">
>   <head>
>       <title>SOMETITLE</title>
>       <somecode>
>   <frameset title="SOMETITLE2" rows="100%,*" onunload="_checkUnload(event)">
>       <frame title="SOMETITLE2" src="/somelink&loc=pl" frameBorder="0" noResize="" longDesc="#">
>       <!--rce quirks mode for ie-->
>       <!--DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" -->
>           <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
>           +<head>
>           <body class="someBody" onload="return _chain('_checkLoad()','self.setTimeout(\'sizeWin(self,0,0,null)\',100);',this,event)" onunload="return _chain('_checkUnload(event)',' if ((window.event.clientY < 0) || (window.event.clientX < 0)){if(_pprRequestCount==0){if (document.getElementById(\'closeWindow\'))document.getElementById(\'closeWindow\').onclick.call();}}',this,event)">
>               <iframe name="_pprIFrame" width="0" height="0" title="" id="_pprIFrame" src="/somelink.gif" frameBorder="0" longDesc="#" style="top: -100px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">
>               <somecode>
>               <table width="100%" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" summary="">
>                   <tbody>
>                       <tr>
>                           <td class="xd5"/>
>                           <td>
>                               <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" summary="">
>                               <div style="top: 0px; position: relative;">
>                                   <table width="790" align="center" style="position: relative;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" summary="">
>                                       <tbody>
>                                           <tr>
>                                               <td vAlign="top">
>                                               <table class="x4m" id="_id24" style="display: none;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" summary="">
>                                               <form name="frmSearch" id="frmSearch" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" onkeypress="return _chain('searchOnEnter(event,\'searchButtonHidden\')','return _submitOnEnter(event,\'frmSearch\');',this,event,true)" action="/somelink.faces?_.8" method="post">
>                                                   +<div style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
>                                                   <div>
>                                                       +<div style="width: 100%; position: relative;">
>                                                       <div id="searchCriteria">
>                                                           <div style="margin-top: 10px;"/>
>                                                           <table class="x4m" id="_id83" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" summary="">
>                                                               <tbody>
>                                                                   +<tr>
>                                                                   <td class="x4s"/>
>                                                                   <td style="vertical-align: top;">
>                                                                       <div class="x4z" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
>                                                                           <table width="100%" border="0">
>                                                                               <tbody>
>                                                                                   <tr>
>                                                                                       <td width="50%">
>                                                                                           <table class="xdh" id="name_c_whole" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" summary="">
>                                                                                               <tbody>
>                                                                                                   <tr>
>                                                                                                       +<td width="130" class="xdj">
>                                                                                                       +<td width="20" class="xdl">
>                                                                                                       <td width="50" class="xdm">
>                                                                                                           <span class="x1b">
>                                                                                                               <input name="name_c" tabIndex="14" class="x1m" id="name_c" style="background-image: none; background-attachment: scroll; background-repeat: repeat; background-position-x: 0%; background-position-y: 0%; background-color: white;" onkeyup=";" type="text" size="40" maxLength="50"/>
>                                                                                                               <script>invokeOnchange('name_coperator');</script>
>                                                                                                               Text - Empty Text Node
>                                                                                                               
>                                                                                                               
>                                                                                                               <some code>
>       <noframes/>
```

Here is the selenium test I wrote to open this frame

```
public class wezel_iframe {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Selenium/IE/IEDriverServer.exe");
baseUrl = "somelink";
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
//capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings",true);
capabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize() ;
}

@Test
public  void  testNowytestselenium() throws Exception {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
driver.get(baseUrl + "somelink/login.jsp");
//<somecode>
String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // current window handle
driver.findElement(By.id("function_add_button_id")).click(); // opens a new window
Thread.sleep(3000);
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus  to newly opened window
}
   driver.manage().window().maximize() ;
        //window is maximasing so it works fine
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame[title='Zawartość']"))); //no exception -sims to work ok
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("_pprIFrame")));//no exception -sims to work ok
    driver.findElement(By.id("name_c")).sendKeys("CMK"); // NoSuchElementException
 driver.close();
 driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
```

the problem is that I cant do anything with objects within this frame, no matter what i do I always get NoSuchElementException

Comment: i have the same problem... any idea??

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some wait, as iframes takes time to load even after web page get loaded.

Put some explicit wait as below:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("_pprIFrame"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me that, I will definitely use it in future, but it didn't work this time

Comment: Actually it led me to answer, it was quite obvious:
name_c wasn't actually in iframe but table mining it was in frame SOMETITLE2
I probably tried that before and it didnt work becouse time to load was too short